# awaitMessages is not triggering when I send a dm to my bot

Tags: javascript, async-await, discord.js

I am trying to push a series of selections made by a user into an array:

```
var dmc = await user.createDM();

function filter (x) {
        if (x.author.id === client.user.id) {
          ...
        }
      };
picks.push({id: game.players[i].id, promise: dmc.awaitMessages({filter, max: 1, time: 60*1000})});
...
var colx = (await picks[i].promise)[0]
```

The objects are successfully pushed into the array, but awaitMessages never resolves when I send the response and always times out.

Edit: I'm not receiving any errors, which is part of the problem. When it gets to the awaitMessages point it just waits indefinitely for the promise to resolve until it times out. No messages I send trigger it. I've tried calling it after the var colx declaration, I've tried console logs, I've tried calling the awaitMessages declaration on its own first and then adding it to the object being pushed. All no luck in resolving the promise. I'm starting to think it has to do with the promise being pushed into the array and me not knowing how to resolve it from within.

Comment: what exactly is the error? what have you tried?

Comment: I'm not receiving any errors, which is part of the problem. When it gets to the awaitMessages point it just waits indefinitely for the promise to resolve until it times out. No messages I send trigger it.
I've tried calling it after the ```var colx``` declaration, I've tried console logs, I've tried calling the awaitMessages declaration on its own first and then adding it to the object being pushed. All no luck in resolving the promise.
I'm starting to think it has to do with the promise being pushed into the array and me not knowing how to resolve it from within.